# Unable to save title after hook_form_alter()

Tags: forms

I have a node form for a specific content type that has many fields.  I want to move these fields into field sets, and wrap that in a class to make it work with my theme.  I've done this with hook_form_alter(), and everything is fine, for the most part.  I am able to save fields, and the form is displayed correctly.

However, whenever I submit the node edit form, the title flips back to 'Array' and gives me the following errors:

```
Warning: mb_strlen() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in drupal_strlen() (line 478 of mysite/includes/unicode.inc).
Notice: Array to string conversion in devel_watchdog() (line 531 of mysite/sites/all/modules/devel/devel.module).
Warning: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in check_plain() (line 1565 of mysite/includes/bootstrap.inc).
```

Here is my implementation of hook_form_alter().  It's very simple; all it does is set up the fieldsets, copy the needed form elements into them, and then unset the original element:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_id_alter()
**/
function my_module_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  switch ($form_id) {
    case 'my_content_type_node_form':
      $form['fieldset1'] = array(
        '#type' => 'fieldset',
        '#title' => t('Fieldset 1'),
        '#collapsible' => TRUE,
        '#collapsed' => FALSE,
        '#prefix' => '<div class="grid_4">',
        '#suffix' => '</div>',
      );
      $form['fieldset2'] = array(
        '#type' => 'fieldset',
        '#title' => t('Fieldset 2'),
        '#collapsible' => TRUE,
        '#collapsed' => FALSE,
        '#prefix' => '<div class="grid_4">',
        '#suffix' => '</div>',
      );
      $form['fieldset3'] = array(
        '#type' => 'fieldset',
        '#title' => t('Fieldset 3'),
        '#collapsible' => TRUE,
        '#collapsed' => FALSE,
        '#prefix' => '<div class="grid_4">',
        '#suffix' => '</div>',
      );

      //move elements into fieldset1
      $form['fieldset1']['title'] = $form['title'];
      unset($form['title']);

      $form['fieldset1']['field_origin_location'] = $form['field_origin_location'];
      unset($form['field_origin_location']);

      $form['fieldset1']['field_task_override'] = $form['field_task_override'];
      unset($form['field_task_override']);

      //move elements into fieldset2
      $form['fieldset2']['field_equipment'] = $form['field_equipment'];
      unset($form['field_equipment']);

      //move elements into fieldset3
      $form['fieldset3']['field_additional_troubles'] = $form['field_additional_troubles'];
      unset($form['field_additional_troubles']);

      $form['fieldset3']['field_resolution'] = $form['field_resolution'];
      unset($form['field_resolution']);

      $form['fieldset3']['field_repair_parts'] = $form['field_repair_parts'];
      unset($form['field_repair_parts']);

      $form['seperator'] = array(
        '#type' => 'markup',
        '#markup' => '<div class="clearfix"></div>',
      );
    break;
  }
}
```

When I run a debugger and step through it at the time of the error, I see that $form_state['node']->title is set to 'Array', but otherwise I can't determine what is setting it to an array.

The error disappears when this form_alter function is commented out or the module is disabled, so I know that something within this function is triggering the error.

Does anyone have clues of where to start looking to solve this issue?  Is there, perhaps, some other thing that I need to do in order to move the form elements?  Maybe I am missing a step?  Or, is this maybe coming from another module's code and if so, is there a method to find that module?

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

When I posted my code on here, I realized that I had a typo in Fieldset 2, where I was using '$form['device']['title'] = ...' instead of '$form['device']['field_equipment'] = ...'

After fixing the typo, everything is working as normal.